# How to install and configure LEGACY BROWSER SUPPORT for CHROME

Tags: google-chrome

I tried to install Google Chrome Frame for IE but, it seems it got retired as of Jan 2014. Also, in that document they mentioned that Legacy Browser Support to automatically switch between browsers.

If your organization wants to take advantage of the Chrome browser, but your users still need to access older websites and apps that require Internet Explorer, you can use Legacy Browser Support to easily and automatically switch between browsers.

So, can anyone can please help me out in installing,configuring LEGACY BROWSER SUPPORT - CHROME Extensions PLZZZ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through the documentation here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en ?

In a nutshell:

- You install the extension (preferably through Chrome's policies) as described in step 2.
- Install the native component - you can push this one through your software provisioning tool of choice as described in step 3.
- Download the administrative templates (ADM or ADMX/ADML and import them)
- Configure the extension. Most importantly you should specify the set of urls that should trigger transitions and which should not cause transitions. There are plenty of examples on step 4 in the linked doc.
- If all is good at this point running Chrome will activate the extension and it will start bumping you back and forth between the browsers.

Another source of information if you are stuck with some detail is the Chrome bug tracker just search for LBS https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=LBS&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Iteration+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles

Hope this helps!
Julian